# magento 2 how i can override the config save controller adminhtml?

Tags: magento2, overrides, magento-2.1.3

> magento_root\vendor\magento\module-config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save.php

how can i override this controller in the magento 2

Comment: http://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/

Comment: i am using this but this is not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Hello for this you have to extend default controller through dependency injection

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<preference for="Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save" type="Sample\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save" />

 </config>
```

you can use and define your code in your own controller like

```
    <?php
    namespace Sample\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config;

    class Save extends \Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save
    {
     public function execute()
     {
     $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Message from new admin controller.');
     return parent::execute();
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But how to get parameters before save config in custom shipping module.

Comment: $this->getRequestParams();